# where to put actionscript in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am not understanding something I believe that flex can run actionscript but every time I try I get different errors.

this time my error is:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Could not resolve <fx:script> to a component implementation.    as.mxml /ar/src line 7  Flex Problem
```

I keep looking at flex tutorials and it's almost like they assume that one knows the ide hence they are just showing the .as code.

I think that everything flash can do flex can do. So why be restricted to only one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <fx:script>
        var socket:XMLSocket;

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doConnect);


        function doConnect(evt:Event):void{
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doConnect);
            socket = new XMLSocket("127.0.0.1", 9001);
            socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
            socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
            }


        function onConnect(evt:Event):void{
            trace("Connected");
            socket.removeEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
            socket.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
            socket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onDataReceived);
            socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onSocketClose);                
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
            }


        function onSocketClose(evt:Event):void{
            trace("Connection Closed");
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
            socket.removeEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onSocketClose);
            socket.removeEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onDataReceived);
            }

        function keyUp(evt:KeyboardEvent):void{
            if(evt.keyCode == 81){
                socket.send("exit");
                }
            else{
                socket.send(evt.keyCode);
                }}

        function onDataReceived(evt:DataEvent):void{
            try{
                trace( "From Server:", evt.data );
                }
            catch(e:Error){
                trace('error');
                }}



        function onError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void{
            trace("Connect failed");
            socket.removeEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
            socket.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doConnect);
            }
    </fx:script>
</fx:Declarations>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you use `fx:Script` with a capital S; not a lowercase S.

Then move your `fx:Script` tag out of the `fx:Declaration` and your code will compile:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        var socket:XMLSocket;

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doConnect);


        function doConnect(evt:Event):void{
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doConnect);
            socket = new XMLSocket("127.0.0.1", 9001);
            socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
            socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
            }


        function onConnect(evt:Event):void{
            trace("Connected");
            socket.removeEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
            socket.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
            socket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onDataReceived);
            socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onSocketClose);                
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
            }


        function onSocketClose(evt:Event):void{
            trace("Connection Closed");
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
            socket.removeEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onSocketClose);
            socket.removeEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onDataReceived);
            }

        function keyUp(evt:KeyboardEvent):void{
            if(evt.keyCode == 81){
                socket.send("exit");
                }
            else{
                socket.send(evt.keyCode);
                }}

        function onDataReceived(evt:DataEvent):void{
            try{
                trace( "From Server:", evt.data );
                }
            catch(e:Error){
                trace('error');
                }}



        function onError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void{
            trace("Connect failed");
            socket.removeEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
            socket.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doConnect);
            }
    </fx:Script>
```

The `fx:Declaration` tag is primarily used for MXML components that are non-visual, such as validators or services.  While `fx:Script` is clearly non-visual it is not usually embeded inside `fx:Declaration`.

Comment: Right so components are things that you can build in flash then export as swc to be used inside the flex app and they get added to the build then referred to in declarations?

Comment: @BenMuircroft It depends how you define "component".  In my experience, the only thing built in Flash Pro and exported for use with Flex are library assets; which are usually graphical assets and/or animations.  Everything else is usually built directly for Flex in Flash Builder (or IntelliJ or whatever your IDE of choice is).

Comment: I thought you could design something like a complex menu or application part (with very odd look and very graphical) with as3 inside its frames then turn it into a component to use in flex. Because flex does not do graphics.

Comment: In theory; you can.  No one ever does.  If you want to design complicated/odd menus why are you using Flex in the first place?  If you aren't using / Styling the built in flex components; I'm not sure why you'd want to use Flex.